# C++ OpenSSL simultaneous incoming connections

Tags: php, c++, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am quite desperate. I have been trying to fix following bug:

## Description of the problem:

If I try to send from PHP to C++ over a TLS TCP socket everything is fine. But if i try to send at the same time (two client website calls - from the same client) i get !!sometimes!! a OpenSSL error from one of the connections:

**(The most time i'm getting this two error messages):**

> 140099339675104:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong
>   version number:s3_pkt.c:389
>
> 140099329185248:error:1408E0F4:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_message:unexpected message:s3_both.c:408:

**OR**

> 140426079958496:error:140940F5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:unexpected
>   record:s3_pkt.c:1645:

## View the code:


As I have already described above i'm using the OpenSSL Library.
At the moment i know, that the problem is generating from the function:
SSL_accept(SSL *ssl);

If a new connection is going to established (i use the blocking mode)

```
accept(basis_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &address, &addrlen)
```

We generate a new **detached thread** for every client socket (I know a thread pool is better. I will implement this feature in the future).

So in every new thread I call the function set_sockfd();

```
bool network::clientsocketaction::set_sockfd(int sockfd, struct ssl_properties ssl_settings) {

this->ctx = ctx;
this->accepted_socket = sockfd;
this->ssl_settings = ssl_settings;

try {

    //Encryption is enabled and a cipher(s) is given.
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_method());

    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);

    /* Set the key and cert */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, ssl_settings.ssl_certificatepath.c_str()) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_cb(print_sslerrors_to_log, NULL);
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, ssl_settings.ssl_keypath.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
        ERR_print_errors_cb(print_sslerrors_to_log, NULL);
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Set ciphers
    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, ssl_settings.ssl_cipher.c_str());

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, this->accepted_socket);


    if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
        std::cout << "mdsfdjsfklj" << '\n';
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

        ssl_use = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        ssl_use = true;
        return true;
    }
} catch(std::exception& e) {
    closeclient();
    return false;
}
}
```

**So the question is why i'm getting those OpenSSL errors?

I hope someone can help me!**

Comment: Probably totally unrelated, but some of the SSL functions you call (especially `SSL_load_error_strings` and `OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms`) shouldn't really be called multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider creating a [mcve] for this issue. By doing so you may find the problem yourself, and if not, you will make it much easier for people like me to grab the code and test it to try to spot any issues.

Comment: @TypeIA First i didn't find anything - or not the right one. Otherwise I would not write. Furthermore SSL is a really complicated subject

Comment: Where is ctx coming from?  A common shared object?

Comment: @N.Men It is, but OpenSSL makes it quite simple really. You can write a complete multi-threaded TLS server in about 100 lines of code. Meaning you should be able to whittle your [mcve] down to about that. Then if you still have the problem you can post it here and I will be happy to try it out and help you. However I don't have the time or inclination to do so without complete functioning code.